# Why does Entity Framework FindFirstOrDefault returns ExecutionException instead of null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have two tables which i execute simple `db.Where(...).FirstOrDefault()` function

```
OWNERS user = db.OWNERS.Where(o => o.username == owner.username).FirstOrDefault(); // works fine
SHOPS m_shop = db.SHOPS.Where(q_shop => q_shop.Name == shop.Name).FirstOrDefault(); // throws exception
```

First one executes the query and returns null if data doesnt exists,the problem is with the second table.
It throws an CommandExecutionException,so i tested executing only

```
SHOPS m_shop = db.SHOPS.Where(q_shop => q_shop.Name == shop.Name);
```

This works too , the only difference between two tables are the Name column is text but the OWNER.username column is nvarchar(MAX) , i tried updating entity framework model but i still get the same exception.

Here is the table definition

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SHOPS] (
    [Id]             DECIMAL (18)   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]           TEXT           NULL,
    [location]       TEXT           NULL,
    [location_coord] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [phone]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [workers_table]  DECIMAL (18)   NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_SHOPS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And my model :

```
    public partial class SHOPS
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public SHOPS()
        {
            this.OWNERSHOP = new HashSet<OWNERSHOP>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public decimal Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string location_coord { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> workers_table { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<OWNERSHOP> OWNERSHOP { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Exception:

"System.InvalidCastException: 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Proje2.Models.Entity.SHOPS]' türündeki nesne 'Proje2.Models.Entity.SHOPS' türüne atılamadı.\r\n   konum: Proje2.Controllers.HomeController.validateUser(SHOPS shop, OWNERS owner) C:\Users\Kutay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Proje2\Proje2\Controllers\HomeController.cs içinde: satır 134"

It says `1[Proje2.Models.Entity.SHOPS]' typed object couldn't be assigned to Proje2.Models.Entity.SHOPS type

Why am i getting an exception ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Catch the exception and log with `exception.ToString()`. Then post that exception stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Done, i was gonna upload the whole stack trace but i guess it would be unneccesary, it says that its a type cast exception

Comment: I've seen a lot of problems with the `TEXT` type, because it is not really text at all, but rather a binary type, just like `VARBINARY`. `TEXT` is unadviceable btw, you should rather use `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Have you tried using a conversion? `SHOPS m_shop = db.SHOPS.Where(q_shop => Convert.ToString(q_shop.Name) == shop.Name).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: i did not let me check it,thank you

Comment: @h3x0r *remove* both `text` and `varchar(max)`. Those types are meant for 2GB-sized text, using special storage. They are *not* meant for general use and will definitely harm performance. I doubt you'll ever encounter such a long phone number. Use sensible lengths instead.

Comment: it still doesnt work,i need this Name column to be more than 255 characters, so i need to make it text,if i cant find an answer i am going to create a stored procedure or try to directly executing sql myself.

Comment: @h3x0r `VARCHAR` can be at maximum `8000` or MAX. `NVARCHAR` can be at maximum `4000` or `MAX`. MAX means a lot. In both cases 8000 and 4000 are not arbitrary numbers, but rather the maximum length that can be searched. There is a lot more to say about the 4000 and 8000 threshold though.

Comment: i think i am going to make it 999 length column and move on to coding rest of the application, i am leaving question open if somebody else finds a good solution, Thank you all for your replies :)

Comment: It's 2020. `TEXT` has been [deprecated for *over a decade*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Does using varbinary(MAX) actually allocates 8.000 bytes of data ? or  does it allocates over need ? if they suggest us to use varbinary(MAX) instead it should has good performance, afaik text only expands when you add more data, and it only reduces performance when you use LIKE clause to compare a text column

Comment: If you're still trying to contemplate `text` vs anything else, you're going badly wrong. You need to **STOP** using `text`. MS have been saying so for many years. It's not some kind of trade-off. The `MAX` datatypes are "not worse" in any manner so far discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was creating a custom query for it,because apperently Entity Framework can't automatically compare text columns

Converting it to this codeline solved my problem.

```
SHOPS m_shop = db.SHOPS.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM SHOPS WHERE Name LIKE '@Name'", new SqlParameter { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Text, ParameterName = "@Name", Value = shop.Name }).FirstOrDefault();
```